# Filter a grouped by result in PostgresSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a planning table like this:

| ID | EmployeeID | ExternalID | JobID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 1 | null | a |
| def | 1 | null | b |
| ghi | null | 2 | a |
| jkl | null | 2 | f |
| mno | 5 | null | d |

I want to filter the rows by using an AND condition between EmployeeID and ExternalID grouping by the JobID. If I want the plannings for Employee 1 and External 2 the result should be:

| ID | EmployeeID | ExternalID | JobID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 1 | null | a |
| ghi | null | 2 | a |

I'm trying using subqueries but the group by is making it hard to then filter the result with a simple `WHERE EmployeeID = 1 AND ExternalID = 2`.

Since the result should be displayed on a frontend table, where the filtering happens, I want it to return all the JobIDs that have the selected Employees and Externals. The JobID is not given beforehand.

Comment: "...I want the plannings for..." -- what do you mean by "planning"?

Comment: @TheImpaler I think "planning" is the name of the table.

Comment: @jjanes oh, you are right. Didn't read it well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution to my problem with this query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            JobID,
            array_agg(EmployeeID) AS employee,
            array_agg(ExternalID) AS external
        FROM
            plannings
        GROUP BY
            JobID
    ) t1
WHERE
    array ['1', '5'] <@ employee -- using array so I can look up multiple IDs
    AND array ['2'] <@ external
```

I had to convert the JobIDs to string in order to use the <@ operator.

https://dbfiddle.uk/KPpiPgmo

Answer (score 1):

We can try to use the condition aggregate function with your condition in a subquery and then filter the count whether greater than 0.

```
SELECT ID,EmployeeID,ExternalID,JobID
FROM (
    SELECT *, 
           COUNT(CASE WHEN EmployeeID = 1 THEN 1 END) OVER(PARTITION BY JobID) cntEmployeeID,
           COUNT(CASE WHEN ExternalID = 2 THEN 1 END) OVER(PARTITION BY JobID) cntExternalID
    FROM T
) t1
WHERE cntEmployeeID > 0 AND cntExternalID > 0
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/-gZxjPRT)

or PostgreSQL support `filter` that we can try to use

```
SELECT ID,EmployeeID,ExternalID,JobID
FROM (
    SELECT *, 
           COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE EmployeeID = 1) OVER(PARTITION BY JobID) cntEmployeeID,
           COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE ExternalID = 2) OVER(PARTITION BY JobID) cntExternalID
    FROM T
) t1
WHERE cntEmployeeID > 0 AND cntExternalID > 0
```

Comment: What if I have multiple EmployeeID? I tried using `EmployeeID IN (1, 5)` and later `(ExternalID in (2)` but it returns also the plannings for 5 that not have 1 and 2 in common. The expected result with the given table should be an empty one (no JobID in common between the three).